# Openstack Newton to Ocata Upgrade

Tags: openstack

I have deployed a 4 node juju bundle based on Openstack Newton via MAAS.  I would like to upgrade this environment via `juju` to `Openstack Ocata`
This is a test environment so I did not perform the pre-req's like backing up configuration files nor databases.   The steps that I am taking to accomplish this upgrade is below i.e. keystone

```
juju config keystone action-managed-upgrade=true
juju config keystone openstack-origin=cloud:xenial-ocata
juju run-action keystone/0 openstack-upgrade
```

First question I have is, do I need to upgrade the juju charm first for keystone in order for it to operate properly once on Ocata.  Second, after doing this updates, any previous `volumes/networks/images/instances` are gone.  I also have a message on my nova-compute nodes indicating `qemu-kvm` service not started.